Does having `content-type: application/octet-stream` necessarily means that we should set request body as a binary form?
I have this sample request with cUrl in the contract (the contract docs only show this for the endpoints):
curl \
    -X PUT \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
    -H 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf \
    --upload-file my-file \
    https://storage.google.apis.com/…..


The endpoints intended to update an image. I have only an image in the base64 string format, and I want to upload this data through this endpoint.

Since the API docs only provide that information, should I directly pass the base64 string as the request body as below:

const dummyBase64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAABjElEQVRIS+2VvUoDQRSGv9V2'

fetch(
    'https://storage.google.apis.com/…',
    {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="dummy.js"'
        },
        body: dummyBase64Image,
    }
)..... // callback handling

Or should I parse the image with the base64 string format into another form (such as parse the base64 string into binary format)?

Is the request sample with cUrl and content-type: application/octet-stream in the documentation enough to conclude that the request body form must be mere a base64 string format (fetch chaining shown above)and not like the usual object that is being passed in the request body with some predetermined field name such as (below fetch chaining):

fetch(
    'https://storage.google.apis.com/…',
    {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="dummy.js"',
        },
        body: {
            image: dummyBase64Image,
        }
    }
)..... // callback handling


You probably need to convert dummyBase64Image to Blob or ArrayBuffer

Yes, you need to convert from base64 format to raw binary format, in a Blob or Buffer, keep in mind that you need to remove the data:image/[extension];base64, because it is just a prefix is used to identify the content in a data URI scheme.
const dummyBase64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAABjElEQVRIS+2VvUoDQRSGv9V2';


function base64ToBlob(base64, mimeType) {
    const byteCharacters = atob(base64.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/, ''));
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 512) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + 512);
        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: mimeType});
}


const imageBlob = base64ToBlob(dummyBase64Image, 'image/png');


fetch('https://storage.google.apis.com/…', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="dummy.png"'
    },
    body: imageBlob,
})

